# How do I edit a button in a grid with only knowing the Grid Row & Column?

Tags: c#, button, grid

I have a grid with some buttons. And basically want to edit the `IsEnabled` state of a `Button` in a specific `Grid Row` + `Column`. I don't get how to do this e.g.

```c#
public void Disablebutton (int Column, int Row)
{
    //disable the button at Grid Row = Row and Grid Column = Column 
}
```

Can someone provide an example how to solve given problem?

---

**EDIT:**

I found a temporary solution... Well, it's working, but it's very bad

```c#
if("B" + x.ToString()+ y.ToString() == "B00")
{
    B00.IsEnabled = false; //B00 is the button name f.e.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're using WPF, Windows Forms or anything else, but you should have a Cell in the datagrid that you access using the row and col values. That cell has the button control that you can cast to a variable to change its properties. Something like this:

```
Button button = (Button)Grid.Cell[Column][Row].Control;
button.IsEnabled = false;
```

or

```
Button button = Grid.Cell[Column][Row].Control as Button
button.IsEnabled = false;
```

Keep in mind that this is a very rough example, since I don't know what technology you're using to paint the interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me alot. Did not know there was a Cell feature.